# Excel Looking for Column ref of the second instance in a row

Tags: excel

I have a table where I an looking at time between orders. it looks something like this;

```
weeks   1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
orders   1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

where zero is an order present for that week overwise the cell is 1 + the previous week number.

I need to find the column ref for the second instance of zero (to find out how long the first order has lasted)

I'm trying to use something like:

```
=SMALL(IF(A2:H2=0,COLUMN(A2:H2),""),2)
```

But all I get `#Value!` error.
When I evaluate the error it seems it doesn't like the `"A2:H2=0"` calculation in the IF. I checked I wasn't screwing up something simple in the insert function tool and on here it gives me the value I want but on the sheet just gives me the `#value!` error...

I tried this with index too but can't seem to get it to work.

Does anyone have any advice to where I'm going wrong?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your formula is correct, but you should make it an array formula. Go into the cell where the formula is placed and hit CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER. your formula gets { } wrapped around itself and shows the desired result.

Comment: That's it! Thank you!